# How do I suppress the counter for figures?

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, memoir

I am including some illustrations in the figure environment so that they float properly and so I can caption them, but I don't want the counter.  Is there a way to suppress this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{illustration}{thp}{lop}

\begin{document}

\begin{illustration}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in,height=5in]{image001}
\caption{{\large \textbf{Caption}}}
\end{center}
\end{illustration}

\end{document}
```

Comment: memoir offers also the command `newfloat` you don't need the package `float`.

Answer (score 6):

The whole answer refers the documentation of memoir:

[CTAN memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir)

You are using `memoir`. `memoir` provides also the command `\newfloat` So you don't need the package `newfloat`. See section *10.1 NEW FLOAT ENVIRONMENTS*

What you want is called by memoir `legend`. So the command `\legend` helps you.

In the documentation you can find:

> The `\legend` command is intended to be used to put an anonymous
>   caption, or legend into a float environment, but may be used anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You could load the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and use the starred version `\caption*`. (The package is also useful for formatting the caption.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{illustration}{thp}{lop}

\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{illustration}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in,height=5in]{image001}
\caption*{Caption}
\end{center}
\end{illustration}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The caption package seems to break memoir somehow.

Comment: @Jeremy: please be more explicit. If you don't provide any concrete information it's almost impossible to guess what the problem might be. You can edit your question and add a MWE showing the problems you are having with the `caption` package.

Comment: The `caption` package should not `break` `memoir` as such, but you do need to remember that the `caption` package replace all of the `memoir` captioning interfaces, so you will need to use the `caption` package equivalents.